# Why only the right hand of the woman is green and different to her skin colour in other parts?

Tags: color, image-quality, white-balance, old-lenses, tint

I am wondering how the woman's writing hand is oddly coloured and so much greener than her tint tone on the other hand?
Does it have to do with the circuit boards around her writing hand or the temperature of the room?
If possible, can you give some optics points of view as well?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: looks like a pretty old photo. How do we know it hasn't just been edited? Where is the original? My guess is dodgy film/scanning. I doubt her hand looked so green at that moment in reality.

Comment: here's another version with _slightly_ different colouring: [https://twitter.com/BrianRoemmele/status/1460381865320214528](https://twitter.com/BrianRoemmele/status/1460381865320214528)

Comment: In case anybody's wondering: Those cabinets behind her look like [_analog computers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer), and those "trays" on the table with masses of wires on them... Those are the _programs_ for the computer. They're called "plugboards" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly some kind of color quantization during the digital history of this picture. It's not only the hand, her jacket also suffers from a color problem and there are plenty of completely white pixels. Her face isn't that clean either, and there is this reddish mark from her ear to her throat that should have been a delicate shadow.

Many of these old pictures have had a past as a GIF later re-encoded as a heavily compressed JPEG (storage wasn't cheap, and screens were small).